# Jbpm connectivity issue

Tags: java, ssl, jbpm

I am trying to connect to JBPM server using https protocol. When I set the trustStore certificate path through VM arguments I am able to connect to the JBPM server but when I set the truststore path through code, I am not able to connect to the server and getting  'no available endpoints found exception'
What could be the root cause for this issue ?  Below is the code snippet which causes 'No available endpoints found' exception. If I use -`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/middleware/tomcat/instances/cloudapp/cert/cacerts*`   in catalina_opts.properties then
then it connects without error.

```
import org.kie.server.client.KieServicesClient;
import org.kie.server.client.KieServicesConfiguration;
import org.kie.server.client.KieServicesFactory;


System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/opt/middleware/tomcat/instances/cloudapp/cert/cacerts");
KieServicesConfiguration config =  KieServicesFactory.
        newRestConfiguration("https://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server",
        "abc",
        "password1!");
 KieServicesClient client = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config);
```